# Save a list in python

Tags: python, export, export-to-csv

I am trying to export my output to a list. Here is my code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

row_list = np.arange(0,5)
for row in row_list:
    a = row + 3
    b = row + 4
    c = row + 5


    result = [a, b, c]
    csvfile = "/home/Desktop/test"

    with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\t')
        for val in result:
            writer.writerow([val])
```

I run the code, a test file is created on my desktop (which is exactly what I want) but the data in the file is wrong.
The output is:
    `7    8    9`

But this is not what I want. The script is running through the loop but it's only exporting the last line. Any ideas on how to get it to export the data in the file in the following manner:

```
3 4 5
4 5 6
5 6 7
6 7 8
7 8 9
```

Thanks!

EDIT: What if I want to give this script to my professor. The directory `/home/paula/Desktop/test` does not exist on her laptop. I tried to write `csvfile = "~/Desktop/test"` but it gave me an error. Any idea?

Note: I am using ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a file in the `w` mode, it erases any existing contents. Even if it didn't, you're not writing a newline character at the end of your lines.

Open the file once, and use a more sensible concept of "row" - one that corresponds to actual rows of your data:

```
with open(csvfile, "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter='\t')

    for row_num in row_list:
        a = row_num + 3
        b = row_num + 4
        c = row_num + 5

        row = [a, b, c]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You `open()` the file again each time through the loop, using `'w'` ((over)write) as the file mode rather than `'a'` (append). See [the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for more on reading and writing files.

Alternatively, open the file *outside* the loop:

```
csvfile = "/home/paula/Desktop/test"
with open(csvfile, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\t')
    for row in rowlist:
        # do the output here
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you open `csvfile` in `w` mode you are truncating it down to 0 bytes. Instead, open the new file in `a` mode, which will append data to it.