# How to add line numbers to an output file?

Tags: python, text, formatting

Write a program that asks the user for a file containing a program and a name for an output file. Your program should then write the program, with line numbers to the output file. For example, if the input file is:

```
def main():
    for i in range(10):
        print("I love python")
    print("Good bye!")
```

Then the output file would be:

```
1   def main():
2       for i in range(10):
3           print("I love python")
4       print("Good bye!")
```

I know how to create a new output file but I have difficulty in adding line numbers to each line. please help! My program is:

```
filename = input("Please enter a file name: ")
filename2 = input("Please enter a file name to save the output: ")

openfile = open(filename, "r")
readfile = openfile.readlines()


out_file = open(filename2, "w")
save = out_file.write(FileWithLines)
```

Comment: Is the newline adjustment part of this problem or was that accidental? (referring to the shift of `print("Good bye!")`)

Comment: Interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268231/python-adding-line-numbers-to-the-output

Answer (score 2):

First, it is best to use the `with ...` syntax when using files (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Then, all you have to do is use `enumerate` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). `enumerate` is a built-in function that takes a sequence (string, list, dict, set, ...) as input and generates tuples with a counter and the corresponding value of the sequence.

```
with open(filename, "r") as openfile:
    with open(filename2, "w") as out_file:
        for j, line in enumerate(openfile):
            out_file.write('{0:<5}{1}'.format(j+1, line))
```

Comment: A quick mention of the return values/types from enumerate would be a nice addition here.  That and/or the documentation page to this function would be great! +1

Comment: can you do it in my way, please? I did not learn with statement

Comment: @malcolm with statements will make your life much easier, particularly with file I/O.  This is an excellent time to learn about `with`!

Comment: @malcom, just look at the code. it is as easy as that ... no need to close the file or do anything else afterwards

Comment: Near the bottom of this documentation page on file I/O you'll see a clean `with` example: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: @BlackVegetable, let me know if that's better.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244672/exporting-a-list-in-python-in-a-for-loop), it describes exactly what you're looking for. Let me know if you need more details.