# Adding line numbers to the output in Python

Tags: python, text, format

For example, if the input file is:

```
def main():
    for i in range(10):
        print("I love Python")
    print("Good bye!")
```

Then the output would be:

```
1   def main():
2       for i in range(10):
3           print("I love Python")
4       print("Good bye!")
```

I have difficulty in adding lines to each line. My program is:

```
filename = input("Please enter a file name: ")
count = 0

openfile = open(filename, "r")

for lines in openfile:
    linenumbers = openfile.write(str(count)+'\t'+lines)
    count += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: I have seen that homework just a few minutes ago from a class mate. He was a bit more studious than you. Please try harder.

Comment: The same exact question, interesting ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267986/how-to-add-line-numbers-to-an-output-file

Comment: @MalikBrahimi It was like a deja vu

Answer (score 4):

Use a with statement to close the file buffer and just concatenate strings:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as program:
    data = program.readlines()

with open('file.txt', 'w') as program:
    for (number, line) in enumerate(data):
        program.write('%d  %s' % (number + 1, line))
```

Comment: Please do it without using with statements. I did not learn it yet!

Comment: Please extend from the program that I wrote. It will be easy for me to comprehend.

Answer (score 3):

You should add:

```
newFile = open(yourfile, 'w')
count = 1

for line in readfile:
    newFile.write (str(count) + '\t' + line)
    count += 1
newFile.close()
```

If you just want to print to console write (this is according to the variable names you've used in your second edit):

```
for lines in openfile:
    print str(count) + '\t' + lines
    count += 1
```

You should do your homework yourself, though!

Comment: what about the print statement at the end?

Comment: Are you missing an open function?

Comment: Yeah, I was like *What's the deal with the tuple?*

Comment: @superDAddy Your edit was mostly correct, but you were never opening a file to write. That's why I rejected your edit.

Comment: @superDAddy what do you mean by "print statement at the end"?

Comment: `filename = input("Please enter a file name: ")`
    `count = 1`

    `openfile = open(filename, "r")`

    `for lines in openfile:`
        `linenumbers = openfile.write(str(count)+'\t'+lines)`
        `count += 1`
        


    `print(linenumbers)`

Comment: why is my edit wrong? I am asking for the file name from the user

Comment: PRINT STATEMENT - it should print out the output with line numbers.

Comment: @superDAddy When you write open(filename, 'r'), 'r' means read only. If you want to write to file you should use 'w'. This is if you want to create a new file with the new format. But if you want to just print to console then add print str(count)+'\t'+line in the for loop I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I would write so:

```
with open(path) as src:
    for index, line in enumerate(src.readlines(), start=1):
        print '{:4d}: {}'.format(index, line.rstrip())
```

or

```
with open(path) as src:
    print '\n'.join(['{:4d}: {}'.format(i, x.rstrip()) for i, x in enumerate(src.readlines(), start=1)])
```