# How to add line numbers to a printed table

Tags: python, enumeration

I have a text file which is called *score.txt*, the contents are:

```
dave 100
ben 50
mary 5
hello 75
elwin 360
didier 1000
ken 85
jibril 79
heyo 900
alan 23
wy 57
sam 99
```

I am using this code:

```
with open ("score.txt") as f:
    for line in reversed(sorted([line.rstrip().split() for line in f],key=lambda x : int(x[1]) )):
        d=("\t".join(line))
        print(d)

with open("scoreboard_sorted.txt","a") as file:
    file = file.write(d+"\n")

with open("scoreboard_sorted.txt") as myfile:
    output=myfile.readlines()[0:10]
    print(output)
```

the results are like this in *scoreboard_sorted.txt*:

```
didier  1000
heyo    900
elwin   360
dave    100
sam     99
ken     85
jibril  79
hello   75
wy      57
ben     50
alan    23
mary    5
```

and for the code:

```
with open("scoreboard_sorted.txt") as myfile:
    output=myfile.readlines()[0:10]
    print(output)
```

The result are:

```
['didier\t1000\n', 'heyo\t900\n', 'elwin\t360\n', 'dave\t100\n', 'sam\t99\n', 'ken\t85\n', 'jibril\t79\n', 'hello\t75\n', 'wy\t57\n', 'ben\t50\n']
```

ok so the problem is i want it to print like this:

```
1. didier   1000
2. heyo     900
3. elwin    360
4. dave     100
5. sam      99
6. ken      85
7. jibril   79
8. hello    75
9. wy       57
10.ben      50
```

Should I add a counter inside?

Comment: Yes, please share your current attempt.

Comment: Also please tag only one programming language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PYTHON- adding line numbers to the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268231/python-adding-line-numbers-to-the-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the content is in file "txt", following code should work in `python`. (though it does not preserve the whitespaces)

```
with open ("txt") as f:
    for line in sorted(
        [line.rstrip().split() for line in f],
        key=lambda x : int(x[1])
    ):
        print(" ".join(line))
```

Simply, in cmdline you can do something like below, while preserving white spaces

```
sort -k 2 -g txt
```

Comment: ok it seems to be working, is it possible to sort it in descending order? like start from 100 instead of 5

Comment: Yes, when you mark the answer as accepted :p
In python you can do "reversed sorted" instead of sorted.
In cmdline you can use '-r' switch

Comment: i still new to this stackoverflow. How do i post a new post below instead of comment? seems cant find an reply instead of comment

Comment: How to sort the file the opposite way?

Comment: Do you mean on cmdline? Use '-r' option

Comment: I mean i want to sort the file from biggest number to the smallest. I use the code above it sort the file in acceding order

Comment: As I mentioned before, use `reversed(sorted(` instead of `sorted` in the code